# Firefox redirecting to old site, though other browsers works good

Tags: firefox, dns, nameservers

I have bought my domain from one domain registrar and set domain forwarding to where my website is hosted. Now I have setup my website on amazon cloud and did all changes as described and changed DNS changes from my domain registrar.

Everything works good from IE and even from inbuilt browser of Eclipse. But Firefox is still taking to the site where site was hosted earlier.

what is the reason and how to resolve? I have cleared the cache related to website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps these links may be of help:

[Firefox invalidate dns cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063496/firefox-invalidate-dns-cache)

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/555-disabling-the-dns-cache-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: Solved the issue by clearing the cache. But question remains, all my website users would need to clear the cache.