# How to clear DNS cache in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, caching, dns

Like in the title, how to clear that cache?
There are some plugins, but its installation is disabled for Firefox Quantum...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dns-flusher/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/clear-dns-cache/

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063496/firefox-invalidate-dns-cache. The answers there have raw config values you can edit to disable the cache for hard refreshes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can take look at `about:networking#dns` which directly lets you clear the cache.

And [Where does Firefox keep cached DNS responses?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1258756) had already been answered by Firefox's Support Team.

ScreenShot:
[image]

By the way for chrome it is `chrome://net-internals/#dns`

Answer (score 14):

1. Open Preferences by typing `about:preferences` in address bar
2. Goto `Privacy & Security` in the menu on the left side
3. In the `History` Section click at the link `clear your recent history` and select:

   - Time range to clear: `Today` (or whatever fits)
   - Under details select `Cache`
   - Submit form with `Clear now`

This worked for me and is the same as the other answer which was down-voted by any reason, maybe people didn't actually try or maybe something else was missing. Not sure if also the DNS cache of the OS needs to be cleared:

- On macOS I typed in command line: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;say DNS cache has been flushed`
- On Windows it should be Start > Type: `cmd` > run: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: This also clears failed DNS queries, whereas the `about:networking#dns` method in another answer does not. Useful if you are making DNS changes.

Answer (score 1):

Restart browser to flush DNS cache.

DNS cache is not stored on disk.

Or type: about:networking (see great answer by [Shakiba Moshiri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241861/4953553))

Answer (score -3):

The new extension framework used by Firefox Quantum doesn't allow functionality like provided by these extensions. That is why they are not being updated to work with Firefox Quantum.

So the way to actually clear the cache is as follows

- Go to the History menu
- Select Clear Recent History
- Check all boxes
- Under Time range to clear select Everything (except passwords, if desired)
- Click Clear Now.

Comment: Yes that is right, but is there any way to clear that cache?

Comment: I updated my answer, it seems I wasn't logged in when I did so.

Comment: There is a difference between browser cache and dns cache

Comment: Of course, but this method should clear the DNS cache of the browser as well