# Firefox doesn't purge DNS cache after network.dnsCacheExpiration intervall

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, dns

Having the latest stable Firefox (69.0.2) on Ubuntu 19.04, I realized that FF has its own DNS cache: After applying DNS changes to the DNS server, I purged the systemd-resolved cache [like described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache/929478#929478). This worked on multiple cli-tools like `dig`, `curl` and `ping`, so the system-wide DNS cache should be purged. But Firefox still got the old DNS record.

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757735/3276634) brings me to `network.dnsCacheExpiration`. According  [to the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Mozilla_networking_preferences), this is the duration in seconds for caching DNS entries. Default is 60 and my `about:config` also shows that 60 is set. However, I updated the DNS record half an hour ago and it's still the old one.

For testing purpose, I also tried it on a Windows 10 test machine with the same Firefox version. Surprisingly, the DNS changes were applied immediately and it also has `network.dnsCacheExpiration` set to 60.

Why is the DNS cache from Firefox not purged after 60 seconds on the Ubuntu machine? Is it a problem of the OS, altouth multiple cli-tools got the new entry?

Comment: Do you see the domain (and expiration time) when you open about:networking#dns page?

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question is stale, I found very little on the topic searching the web that was helpful.  I noticed the same thing that Lion's question outlined, and tried numerous settings that were not successful, such as:

- network.trr.excluded-domains,
- network.dnsCacheExpiration,
- network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod

I found the bugzilla tickets below, which while not directly answering the question, did deal with a related issue with the hosts file not being honored:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1600597
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453207

The tickets also were not very helpful in their analysis.  I did however find three workarounds that worked for me (and hopefully it may help others as well):

- To clear Firefox's DNS cache manually:

  - goto: about:networking#dns > Clear DNS Cache
- To get the DNS cache to work decently with a particular domain:

  - goto: about:config > network.dns.forceResolve > list domain(s)
- To disable Firefox's DNS cache (force it to always resolve without using DNS cache - has a performance impact):

  - goto:  about:config > network.dnsCacheEntries > set it to 0

Comment: I was unaware of these settings very handy

Comment: Same conclusion here, I tried everything. The strange thing is that the bug is only for certain domains, e.g. facebook.com and youtube.com. For yahoo.fr for example, the DNS is cleared, and I have an error as expected if I set the set to the DNS entry to 127.0.0.1 in my /private/etc/hosts file. Thanks for the investigation, the two bugs are still open.